# Recover/move ZFS pool to a new server

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I have a Ubuntu server set up with a 14-disk ZFS raidz2 pool.

My boot device has become corrupted and I'm not able to mount its file system from a recovery live CD, so I will need to reinstall Ubuntu on a new boot drive and bring back my ZFS pool.

Unfortunately, I do not have any record or backups of the pool configuration.  I know the drives were assigned `/dev/sda` through `/dev/sdn` and that these were members of a ZFS pool named `tank`.

Is there a way to recover a ZFS pool with just the media and nothing else?  Does `zfs import` have enough to restore the pool just by examining the drives?

Comment: What does zpool list say ? Does it say there is no pool ? Did you try zpool import -D to list destroyed pools ?

Comment: Check this thread - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483465/restore-zfs-pool-and-storage-data-after-a-system-re-install

Comment: @batistuta09 Thanks for the link.  After further troubleshooting, the OS drive was mountable in ro,noload mode which means there was something wrong with the journalled file system.  I was able to clone the drive to a portable SSD and boot from it normally.  Anybody who finds this question later should refer to your link.